# Gitlab CI: manually run single tasks

Tags: gitlab-ci

I'm trying to migrate some old Jenkins stuff to Gitlab CI/CD. I got the CI/CD part sorted out, that works fine - but I have a couple of "odd jobs" that do stuff like "mirror the production database to the staging environment", "mirror production user uploaded assets to staging" and the likes.

How do I express this in Gitlab CI syntax? `when:manual` jobs don't (really) cut it as the "odd jobs" are totally independent of any pipelines and are needed maybe once a half year tops?

Comment: Don't quite understand; what's wrong with using `when: manual`? Do you have a monorepo and are worried that the `when: manual` will block the pipeline? You can [set](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#allow_failure) `allow_failure: true`. You can also set `needs: []` if it doesn't depend on any job.

Comment: No, but when I have a stage that is set to run as `when:manual`, how do I prevent *all the other parts of the pipeline* from running?

Comment: Do you have a diagram of what you envisage this pipeline to look like? Sounds like you just want one part of the pipeline to run manually?

Comment: Exactly, these "odd jobs" should not be a regular part of any pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create a separate repo and put all of your odd jobs there, after this, for each one, create a template file to be used on demand. Check the docs https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#include
2. In your pipeline use only/except filters to load these templates
   https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-advanced

You will be able to handle the behaviour of your pipeline for example

If commit message contains [mirror-db] load the template mirror-db.yml from odd-jobs repository

```
include:
  - project: 'my-group/odd-jobs'
    file: '/templates/.db-mirror.yml'
```

your .db-mirror.yml file

```
db-mirror:
  stage: odd-job
  script: 
    - echo something
  only:
    refs:
      - master
      - schedules
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /[db-mirror]/
```

Answer (score 0):

These "odd jobs" are not part of your CI pipeline, as you mentioned.  Why not put them in their own repo?